# AnyLogice Text communication

Tags: java, anylogic

i was trying to build a small text comunication model following the steps from "the big book of simulation" chapter 11 and i got an erorr: Description: The method printIn(String) is undefined for the type TextFile. Location: textconnection1/Main/writeToLog - Function
and i would not let me modifiy the java file to fix it.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SOF. Please add a screenshot of the error and (more importantly) the code that triggers the error. Very hard to help "blindly". Some tips for asking great questions here for AnyLogic users see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow